# what does int cannot be dereferenced mean here

Tags: java, generic-programming

```
//Listener for the preorder button
jbtPreOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        key = Integer.parseInt(jtfKey.getText());
        if (!tree.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter something in the tree");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, key + " ");
            preorder(key.left);
            preorder(key.right);
        }
    }
});
```

In the preorder it says int cannot be dereferenced even when the variable is global.

Comment: Give the *exact* error message, and the line on which it occurs.

Comment: and please show the content of 'preorder'.

Comment: @ChrisMartin InitialBSTShow.java:88: error: int cannot be dereferenced
         preorder(key.left);
                     ^
InitialBSTShow.java:89: error: int cannot be dereferenced
           preorder(key.right);
                       ^
2 errors

Answer (score 2):

Key is a an int and int is a primitive. You cannot call methods on a primitive, only an object. Key should really be a string because you are calling get text and hence retrieving characters and not numbers....

Comment: @HarshJoshi We can't really read code that is posted in comments. Edit your question to add code and details.

Answer (score 0):

```
        preorder(key.left);
        preorder(key.right);
```

Exactly the error it self explaining that here `key` is a primitive datatype (int).
you are using primitive datatype (here int) `key` as a reference variable.

So,you cannot dereference using `key` since it is not holding any object.